# Fill upp an entire box with a button in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Problem**

Covering an entire box area with a button using Bootstrap and custom CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="servive-block servive-block-orange">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control">SÖK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.servive-block {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.servive-block-orange {
  background: #e75113;
}
```

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

https://jsfiddle.net/wubegbqb

**Output**

[image]

**Desired output**

Making sure the entire blue button will cover the div area and that the button is clickable.

Comment: Why do you have padding on the box if you want it covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning should work:

```css
.servive-block {
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.servive-block-orange {
  background: #e75113;
}
.full-size {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="servive-block servive-block-orange">
    <div class="form-group full-size">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control full-size">SÖK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wubegbqb/3)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a height and width set on your parent div (.servive-block) you can then set the button to be 100% width and 100% height.

```
.servive-block {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width:250px;
 }

.servive-block .form-group {
    width:100%;
   height:100%;
}


.servive-block .form-group .btn {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: The `form-group` element is the fly in your peanut butter here.